Erratic Performance of CLUSTER in PostgreSQL
I work with PostgreSQL 12 and have partitioned tables that I am trying to cluster. Each partition is roughly the same size in terms of GB. However, the performance can vary significantly, ranging from 5 to 1000 minutes of clustering time per partition.
I am clustering several partitions in parallel, and my database is currently not receiving any requests other than CLUSTER requests.
I do not fully understand the ins and outs of the CLUSTER process under the hood. What could explain such large variations in clustering time, and what can I do to enhance performance?
EDIT : To be more precise, I have a 34 GB partition that was clustered in 13 minutes, and a 56 GB partition clustered in 1288 minutes (almost a day). Those size values are the size before clustering. I am recomputing the sizes.
Query used to retrieve the size :
SELECT table_name, 
       pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(table_schema || '."' || table_name || '"')) AS size
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'partitionschema' and table_name like 'mytable_%' order by table_name;

I did not do ANALYZE or VACUUM before clustering though.
I have 900MB/s disk I/O, and 128GB RAM (although only 40-ish seems to be used according to my datadog dashboard). It also does not seems like my processors are a limitation.
I have 300 partitions to cluster, at each step in the process, am trying to cluster 8 partitions in parallel. Each of theses partitions are in the ~50GB
Some other infos :

maintenance_work_mem: 4GB
work_meme: 64MB
shared_buffer: 32GB
max_wal_size: 4GB


I do not have the authorizations on my other env where tables were not clustered. I will try to provide some values on Monday. But I did not ran ANALYZE, so is it possible that the informations from information_schema are still the old infos ?

The size values provided were the size before clustering, I did not ran an analyze after, I reconfirmed it today by checking on another env. Also, I checked, autovacuum is active

Finally found my answer !
In the documentation, it is mentioned that CLUSTER can use 2 methods to get data from the table where CLUSTER is applied on.

Index scan : slower, sorts the data progressively by reading the data directly in a sorted fashion through an index scan.

Seq scan : read all the data sequentially, then sort them. The operation needs to use a temp file if it does not fit in ram, so potentially consume disk space.


By default, the method is chosen automatically, but you can force an Index Scan with set enable_sort = 'off;, and a Seq Scan with set enable_indexscan = 'off;'
On my ~150M rows table, checking the table pg_stat_progress_cluster, the Index Scan read speed was of 100-300 tuples/sec, vs 100K tuples/sec for the Seq Scan.
I was using the default automatic planning setting, and I think that in my first example, a Seq Scan was used, and an Index Scan in my second clustering.
My final solution was to run
set enable_indexscan = 'off'; CLUSTER ...;

I still do not totally understand why my index scan is so slow, but I probably will have to live with it.
